# Clojure, mapping with a cycle of functions

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

new to clojure, so maybe I am going about this totally the wrong way and all, but is there a way to do this type of thing?

(map (cycle [+ -]) [1 1 1] [1 1 1])

I would want it to return, in this example; (2 0 2)

Thanks to the help below, the solution is:

```
(map (fn [a b c] (a b c)) (cycle [+ -]) [1 1 1] [1 2 3])
```

or

```
(map #(%1 %2 %3) (cycle [+ -]) [1 1 1] [1 2 3])
```

for short

Comment: `(map #(apply % %&) (cycle [+ -]) [1 1 1] [10 10 10] [100 100 100] ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes -

```
(map #(%1 %2 %3) (cycle [+ -]) [1 1 1] [1 1 1])
;;(2 0 2)
```

`#` is a short hand for an anonymous function and `%` is the number of the argument passed. So you are just running `map` against
 `(+ 1 1)`,`(- 1 1)`,`(+ 1 1)`

Comment: Is there a way to do it with an arbitrary number of cycles? like, if my [1 1 1] arrays were also cycles, and I wanted to take n from the output of this whole thing. does that make sense?

Comment: You mean like this? `(take 10 (map #(%1 %2 %3) (cycle [+ -]) (repeat 1) (repeat 1)))`

Comment: [map](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map) returns a lazy sequence. You can execute it against infinite sequences and use `take` to "prevent" it from running forever.  Also, note that it will run ... _until any one of the colls is
exhausted. Any remaining items in other colls are ignored._

Comment: Ah I see. I was thinking that the %3 meant i was limited to running though the function 3 times (there happened to be 3 elements in each vector). Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes sorry. `#(%1 %2 %3)` is short hand for `(fn [a b c] (a b c))`

Comment: what would be the equivalent of: (reduce (cycle [+ -]) [1 2 3])? I have tried a few things, and  (reduce #(%1 %2) (cycle [+ -]) [1 2 3]) does not work

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to map needs to be a function that will be applied to each element of the collections. What you have instead is a vector of functions. So what you need is a function that will apply each element of the vector to the corresponding elements in the other vectors. Like so:

```
(map #(%1 %2 %3) (cycle [+ -]) [1 1 1] [1 1 1])
```

Comment: must be right since we came up with the same answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I am wondering why it does not work for reduce, as in: (reduce #(%1 %2) (cycle [+ -]) [1 10 100]) -to return 91

Comment: @user2251284: Because `reduce` has a different signature than `map`. `map` takes a function as its first argument and then any number of collections, and then it passes corresponding elements from each collection to the function. `reduce` takes a function of two arguments, then either a collection or an initial value and a collection. In order to do this with `reduce`, you'd need to include the cycle of functions in either the seed value or the data itself. Something like `(reduce (fn [acc [f val]] (f acc val)) 0 (->> [1 10 100] (interleave (cycle [+ -])) (partition 2)))`.